# IOS Deep linking is not opening the app directly. it doesn't load or open anything in chrome

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, apple-app-site-association, react-native-deep-linking

I've implemented the deep linking functionality in react native(ios).
also setup the AASA file to the domain.validated it with [branch.io](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) everything seems fine.
i tried many suggestions but still no luck.
Thank you in advance.

For more info.
i added this code in my AppDelegate.m file suggested as [React Native Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/).

```
(BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
openURL: (NSURL *)url
options: (NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
 {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application: application openURL: url options: options];
  }

    (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity: (nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
restorationHandler: (nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable)) restorationHandler
  {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application: application
continueUserActivity: userActivity
restorationHandler: restorationHandler];
  }
```

Enabled the Associated domains with applinks: mydomain.com
added this code in info.plist for refer to incoming links

```
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
 <string>Editor</string>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
 <string>bundle.cp</string>
 <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
 <array>
 <string>verifySuccessResetPassword</string>
 </array>
 </dict>
```

added this prefixes in root navigation https://example.com/verifyEmailSuccess but still no luck.
What's happening like when specific url hit in safari in debug mode app opens automatically and works fine but in chrome browser this link doesn't work.
and in when i try with IPA deeplinking doesn't work with safari neither with chrome, it just loads the webpage nothing more.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you